# Eclipse console text trouble when running arquillian cucumber JVM tests

Tags: java, eclipse, cucumber-jvm, jboss-arquillian

When i'm running cucumbers java tests from eclipse the cucumber jvm is outputting wrong texts on console... 
It's printing this:

```
[32mWhen[0m[32mclica no botão '[0m[32m[1mbuscarButton[0m[32m'[0m
```

I don't know why it is printing this squares

I'm currently using

```
com.github.cukespace:cukespace-core:1.5.10
info.cukes:cucumber-picocontainer:1.1.8
info.cukes:cucumber-junit:1.1.8
```

Comment: Could it possibly be related to the character encoding of your feature files?

Comment: Nope, they are UTF-8 and is just on eclipse console. Also, i tried the #encoding: utf-8 on feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wasn't encode problem, I have found the problem. The cucumber from `info.cukes` is trying to print the text with syntax colors that works perfect on terminal but not in eclipse console.

If someone have the same problem, need to change to **monochrome** mode

At **arquillian.xml**

```
<arquillian...
  <extension qualifier="cucumber">
    <property name="colors">--monochrome</property>
    <property name="report">true</property>
    <property name="report-directory">target/cucumber-report</property>
  </extension>
 ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The Eclipse console doesn't use UTF-8 by default.  You can change the encoding for a particular Run Configuration at "Run -> Run Configuration" and then the "Common" tab, you can change the encoding away from the Default by selecting "Other" and choosing "UTF-8" from the drop down.

For more information: http://decoding.wordpress.com/2010/03/18/eclipse-how-to-change-the-console-output-encoding/

Comment: by the way, i didn't know that you could change the console encode... thks for your comment

Answer (score 0):

1. Use **monochrome=true** option in your main class as below and get satisfied with normal fonts in Console,

> ```
>   @RunWith(Cucumber.class)
>   @CucumberOptions(
>         features = "Feature",
>         glue={"stepDefinition"},
>         monochrome=true //like this
>         )
> ```

2. Download this add-on (*that can be switched on or off*) in Eclipse and stay rich with Colorful formatting in the Console,

   https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/ansi-escape-console